# Looking for a Sound Forge Audio Studio similar program on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, gnome, sound

Today I learned that in this semester we must use Sony's Sound Forge Audio Studio program, which is used to work with different audio files, etc.
So I am curious if you can recommend me something similar on Ubuntu, because I don't want to reinstall Windows or dual-boot just to use it.

Comment: So you are looking for software similar to  Sound Forge Audio Studio program on Ubuntu? Please change your title accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Openshot `sudo apt-get install openshot`.

Alternatively, there is a multimedia official operating system called [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/)

### About

---

Ubuntu Studio is a free and open source operative system, and an official flavor of Ubuntu. Ubuntu Studio is the most widely used multimedia orientated GNU/Linux distribution in the world. It comes preinstalled with a selection of the most common free multimedia applications available, and is configured for best performance for the Ubuntu Studio defined workflows: Audio, Graphics, Video, Photography and Publishing.

#### Feature Tour

---

Ubuntu Studio is a Linux-based operating system designed as a free, open, and powerful platform for creative people to create their art.

Ubuntu Studio is Free and Open Source Software (FOSS), which means it is free to download and use. You can get the source code, study it and modify it. You can redistribute Ubuntu Studio and can even redistribute your modified version. Read more about these freedoms at GNU.org’s Free Software page.

As an officially recognized derivative of Ubuntu, Ubuntu Studio is supported by Canonical Ltd. and an [amazing and continually increasing community](http://www.ubuntu.com/community).

Ubuntu Studio is released every six months, but a long term release (LTS) version is released only every 2 years.

Comment: More audio-specific would be [audacity](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/audacity/).

Comment: Yes Audacity which also comes pre-installed with Ubuntu Studio. There is also, [Ardour](http://ardour.org/), which is a full fledged, Digital Audio Workstation which is suitable, but not limited for recording, mixing and mastering.